# How to convert u'\x96' to u'&#x96;' in python

Tags: python, html, utf-8

I'm porting content from an old Wordpress blog to [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org). I was given a json dump of the database and the posts are littered with special characters that look like this: `\x96` among otherwise unescaped html.

If I manually `replace` the slash with `&#` and append a semicolon the character renders correctly

so `\x96` to `&#x96;`

escaped UTF-8(hex) to HTML Entity(hex)

How to do this in Python?

Comment: Does it need to be `&#x96;`?  Or does `&#150;` work?  If yes, `u'\x96'.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')` does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `&#150;` is also acceptable, you can use:

```
>>> u'\x96'.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
'&#150;'
```

which is even called out in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type)<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>(although not very clearly)...</sup>